# JavaScript: Sum of all Evens in a Matrix Using Array Methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, filter, reduce

I'm working on a problem and would like to use array methods to solve it.

My code below I think is close but i can't get it to return the right number.

Goal: Create a function that returns the sum of all even elements in a 2D matrix.

```
function sumOfEvens(arr) {

  // filter for events, push to new array, then sum

  let evenArr=arr.reduce((a,e) => a.concat(e) ,[])
  return evenArr.reduce((a,e) => {
    if (e%2===0){
      console.log(e)
     a+e;
    }
  },0) 
}

sumOfEvens([
  [1, 0, 2],
  [5, 5, 7],
  [9, 4, 3]
]) //➞ should return 6
```

My output is undefined but my console log returns correctly: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `reduce` callback, you need to return the next value of the accumulator. So do `return a + e`, and in an `else`, `return a`:

```js
function sumOfEvens(arr) {

  // filter for events, push to new array, then sum

  let evenArr = arr.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e), [])
  return evenArr.reduce((a, e) => {
    if (e % 2 === 0) {
      return a + e;
    } else {
      return a;
    }
  }, 0)
}

console.log(sumOfEvens([
  [1, 0, 2],
  [5, 5, 7],
  [9, 4, 3]
])) //➞ should return 6
```

You can also consider using `.flat` and `.filter` instead:

```js
const sumOfEvens = arr => arr
  .flat()
  .filter(num => num % 2 === 0)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(sumOfEvens([
  [1, 0, 2],
  [5, 5, 7],
  [9, 4, 3]
])) //➞ should return 6
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to return value inside reduce after every iteration
- `a+e` doesn't change value of `a`, you need to assign it back to `a` to see changed value i.e `a += e`

```js
function sumOfEvens(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, e) => a.concat(e), [])
    .reduce((a, e) => {
      if (e % 2 === 0) {
        a += e;
      }
      return a
    }, 0)
}

console.log(sumOfEvens([[1, 0, 2],[5, 5, 7],[9, 4, 3]]))
```

Comment: ah, thx; I assume the need to return the accumulator is standard whenever using array methods?

Comment: @PineNuts0 yes, `Your reducer function's returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value.` [`MDN Ref`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)